# combine objects of data frame in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

[image]

I want to convert those objects to a long string like this, without the column's name `salary`:

```
23400;26800;9878;6754;7654;28907;6679
```

What should I do?

Comment: Something like `paste(df$Salary, collapse = ";")` but this question is probably a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `x`:

`paste0(x$salary,collapse=';')`